# How to print a string within a for loop but only once?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and wanted to implement a simple for loop:

```
phone_number = input("Please print phone number: ")
for i in phone_number:
    if i=="-":
        continue
    print(i, end="")
```

so as you can see, the point of the program is to print the inputted phone number (111-222-3333) without "-" so the output is: 1112223333.

But I want the output to be "Your phone number is: 1112223333." I do not know how to implement the part that reads

```
print("Your phone number is: ")
```

I have tried to put this statement within the for loop but because of the `end=""` put in

```
print (i, end="")
```

I get a response that reads like

```
Your phone number is:
Your phone number is:1
Your phone number is:1
Your phone number is:1,...
```

I only want the statement to be printed once. What should I do???

Comment: just add `print("Your phone number is: ", end="")` before the loop (but after `input` obvs)

Comment: why not skip the loop, e.g. with `print("Your phone number is: " + phone_number.replace("-", ""))`? see [string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) docs for more info about the string methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your for loop method, you can do the following to achieve your goal:

```py
phone_number = input("Please print phone number: ")

print("Your phone number is: ", end="")
for i in phone_number:
    if i == "-":
        continue
    print(i, end="")
print()
```

Note how I've added an indent before the line `print(i, end="")` so that it is done once per loop, rather than after the `for` has finished.

I also moved the "your phone number is" part to before the loop, so that it is only printed once before any of the numbers are printed.

---

If you wanted, you could also invert the `if` condition to achieve the same result in 1 less line:

```py
for i in phone_number:
    if i != "-":
        print(i, end="")
print()
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating over the characters of the string and printing each character separately, we can remove the `'-'` by using [`str.replace(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
phone = '111-222-3333'
print(f"Your phone number is: {phone.replace('-','')}")
```